# Jenkins - Can't execute stage in Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline

On Docker Toolbox I have pulled and started jenkins container with privilleged mode:

```
docker run -d --security-opt label=disable --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

I installed sugested plugins and created pipeline with following script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After build was triggered following error appeared in build console:

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test@tmp/durable-148d5c09/script.sh: docker: not found
```

Why this error occcurs? What should I do if I want to use docker containers as agents for building stages? :)

**Thanks for help!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Docker installed on the Jenkins Docker container. So you need to install it first, which involves adding a new APT repository.

When you accomplished that, you still to to handle the docker-in-docker problem(s).

Have a look into [this article](https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci). It describes quite well which steps are required and why.

Comment: Just beat me to it. I would bake docker into the Jenkins image though. Maybe do it through docker hub so it can track the Jenkins lts version

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn Well the article references a docker imager from docker-hub.

Comment: yes. All the apt-get stuff could be in a Dockerfile, rather than execing in to add it.